# Apache PDFBox Merge Error - java.io.IOException: Missing root object specification in trailer

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to merge two existing PDF documents that are `InputStreams` together using the `PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments()` method in PDFBox.  Here's my code; the entry method is `pullDocumentsIntoSystem()`:

```
private boolean pullDocumentsIntoSystem(final String id, final String filePathAndName, final List<Letter> parsedLetters)
        throws IOException {

    final List<InputStream> pdfStreams = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
    final ByteArrayOutputStream mergedPdfOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // make a call to retrieve each document
            for (final Letter letter : parsedLetters) {
                pdfStreams.add(this.getSpecificDocument(letter.getKey(), id));
            }

            // merge all the documents together
            this.mergePdfDocuments(pdfStreams, mergedPdfOutputStream);

            // write file to directory
            this.writeMergedPdfDocument(mergedPdfOutputStream, filePathAndName); //...more code below...

}

private InputStream getSpecificDocument(final String id, final String key) throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    InputStream pdfStream = null;

    try {
        final String url = this.getBaseURL() + "/letter/" + id + "/documents/" + key;

        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Letter-Authentication", this.getAuthenticationHeader());
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/pdf");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);          

        pdfStream = connection.getInputStream();

    }
    finally {
        this.disconnect(connection);
    }

    return pdfStream;
}

    private void mergePdfDocuments(final List<InputStream> pdfStreams, final ByteArrayOutputStream mergedPdfOutputStream)
        throws IOException {

    final PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();

    merger.addSources(pdfStreams);

    merger.setDestinationStream(mergedPdfOutputStream);
    merger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());  // ERROR THROWN HERE
}
```

Here's the error I'm receiving on the line with the comment above:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Missing root object specification in trailer.   
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseTrailerValuesDynamically(COSParser.java:2832) ~[pdfbox-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]     
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:173) ~[pdfbox-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]   
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:220) ~[pdfbox-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]  
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1144) ~[pdfbox-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]  
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1060) ~[pdfbox-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]  
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.legacyMergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:379) ~[pdfbox-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]  
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:280) ~[pdfbox-2.0.11.jar:2.0.11]
```

I am using PDFBox 2.0.11.

My list of `InputStream`s are each coming from a separate `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()` call in case that matters.  I have confirmed that there are indeed documents coming back from the calls being made in the `HttpURLConnection`.

### UPDATE


On the advice of @Tilman Hausherr below, I tested the same functionality without using the `InputStream`s.  If I use `PDFMergerUtility.addSource(File source)` method instead the `PDFMergerUtility.addSource(List<InputStream>)` the merge works successfully.  So it seems as if something with my `InputStream`s isn't working correctly.

I appreciate any help and am happy to provide more information if needed.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please reformat the error message using `code` formatting, not blockquote.

Comment: Please verify that you are also getting this error when calling load() on the files without using http. This type of error usually comes from badly corrupted / truncated PDF files. If possible, share the files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the files.  However, I took your suggestion and pulled the same files down from the http call, stored them locally, and then used the `PDFMergerUtility.addSource(File source)` method instead the `PDFMergerUtility.addSource(List<InputStream>)` method.  And it worked.  So the PDFs are valid if written to a local directory first.  Unfortunately, I need to use the streaming solution.  So what could be wrong with the `InputStream`s?  Thanks for your help with this; I will update the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this was really a silly mistake.  I was closing the `HttpURLConnection` too early.  If I remove the `this.disconnect(connection)` call at the end of the `getSpecificDocument()` method then everything works fine.

Well, hopefully this will help someone else.

Thanks for the leads @Фарид Азаев and @Tilman Hausherr!

Comment: Yeah, from the later edited code it's obvious what happens :-) Now don't forget to do that disconnect after you got all of your stream or you may have leaks. One solution could be to transfer it into a ByteArrayOutputStream with IOUtils.copy(), and then return a byte[] (this is faster than returning a stream, which PDFBox will copy into a buffer or a file). If your PDFs aren't too big / too many.

Comment: Yes, I am still disconnecting...but now at the right time.  :)  Also, about your suggestion to use the `IOUtils.copy()`...I am going to have some very large PDFs, perhaps a few hundred pages.  Is the `ByteArrayOutputStream` still an option with files that size?

Answer (score 0):

probably problem in input stream try adding application/pdf mime type.

Comment: I added more code so that you can see the details of my `HttpURLConnection`.  I have the "Accept" and "Content-Type" request properties set as "application/pdf".